# Wrapper class and displaying data in table lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, wrapper-class

Need your help in structuring my wrapper class. 
Price agreement Header (Parent): Has 3 child.Distributor object : Distributor_Eligibility__c ,Product :Product_Pricing__c,Enduser object Direct_Customer_Eligibilities__c

I want the below scenario to be display in my table in lightning component.

case 1: Distributor login (Contact record of type distributor ) and click on search (this is my button on click i am displaying the table):

```
    Distributor List display with only Price agreement header details.
```

Case 2: Distributor login| enter Product value (text box) |click on search:

```
    Distributor List display with Price agreement header + product details.
```

Case 3: Distributor login| End user value(text) |click on search:

```
    Distributor List display with Price agreement header + end user details.
```

Issue is: with case 2 3 . One price agreement header can have multiple product attached to it. same with end user. How to display list of product and end user in the table.

```
public without sharing class ExternalCVTQueryBuilder {

  Public class MainWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Price_Agreement_Header__c priceAgreementHeader {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String validFromFormatted {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String validToFormatted {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public Product_Pricing__c product {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public Direct_and_End_Customer_Eligibility__c endUser {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String DistributorNumber {get;set;}  
        @AuraEnabled
        public String CustomerNumber{get;set;}  
    }

    private List<MainWrapper> fetchResults(Set<Id> pricingHeaderSet) {

       Set<Id> pricingHeaderSet---- This set contain price agreement header (parent) Id's
        ---------------------------------------
        ---------------Code for iterating list of child record from above parent id set-----
        --- list of child record : distributorValidList--------------

       if(distributorValidList.size() > 0) {

           //return distributorValidList;

           // ----------------------My code starts here to return a Wrapper instead of list--------------

           List<MainWrapper> lstMainWrapper = new List<MainWrapper>();
           Map<Id, String> distmap = new Map<Id, String>();

           for(Distributor_Eligibility__c thisnewDist : distributorValidList){
             distmap.put(thisnewDist.Price_Agreement__c,  thisnewDist.Distributor_Number__c);
           } 


           Map<ID, Price_Agreement_Header__c> priceheadermap = new Map<ID, Price_Agreement_Header__c>([SELECT Id,Name,Price_Agr_Description__c,Sub_Grouping__c,Valid_From__c,Valid_To__c,
                                                                                                                 Last_Changed_Date_time__c,Price_Agreement_Status__c,
                                                                                                                 (SELECT Id,Material_Number__c,Valid_From__c, Valid_To__c From Product_Pricings__r)
                                                                                                                 FROM Price_Agreement_Header__c where Id IN: distmap.KeySet()]);

              for(Distributor_Eligibility__c thisnewDist : distributorValidList){
                //Only Product is entered
                if((selectedFilter.product != null && ! String.isEmpty(selectedFilter.product)) && 
                                (selectedFilter.endUserNumber == null || String.isEmpty(selectedFilter.endUserNumber))) {

                   Price_Agreement_Header__c thisHeader = priceheadermap.get(thisnewDist.Price_Agreement__c);
                   if(thisHeader.Product_Pricings__r.size() > 0) {

                       for (Product_Pricing__c productPricing : thisHeader.Product_Pricings__r) {

                          If(selectedFilter.product == productPricing.Material_Number__c){
                             MainWrapper displayWrapper = new MainWrapper();
                             displayWrapper.priceAgreementHeader = thisHeader;
                             displayWrapper.validFromFormatted = thisHeader.Valid_From__c.format();
                             displayWrapper.validToFormatted = thisHeader.Valid_To__c.format();
                             displayWrapper.DistributorNumber = thisnewDist.Distributor_Number__c;
                             productPricing.ValidFromFormated__c =   productPricing.Valid_From__c.format();
                             productPricing.ValidToFormated__c =   productPricing.Valid_To__c.format(); 
                             displayWrapper.product = productPricing;  
                             lstMainWrapper.add(displayWrapper); 
                          }

                      }  
                  }
                  else {
                     system.debug('######### No Product ############');
                     MainWrapper displayWrapper = new MainWrapper();
                     displayWrapper.priceAgreementHeader = thisHeader;
                     displayWrapper.validFromFormatted = thisHeader.Valid_From__c.format();
                     displayWrapper.validToFormatted = thisHeader.Valid_To__c.format();
                     displayWrapper.DistributorNumber = thisnewDist.Distributor_Number__c;

                     lstMainWrapper.add(displayWrapper);
                     }
               }

              //Only End User is entered
              else if((selectedFilter.endUserNumber != null && ! String.isEmpty(selectedFilter.endUserNumber)) &&
                                 (selectedFilter.product == null || String.isEmpty(selectedFilter.product))){

             Price_Agreement_Header__c thisHeader = priceheadermap.get(thisnewDist.Price_Agreement__c);

             MainWrapper displayWrapper = new MainWrapper();
             displayWrapper.priceAgreementHeader = thisHeader;
             displayWrapper.validFromFormatted = thisHeader.Valid_From__c.format();
             displayWrapper.validToFormatted = thisHeader.Valid_To__c.format();
             displayWrapper.DistributorNumber =  thisnewDist.Distributor_Number__c;

                     if(thisHeader.Direct_Customer_Eligibilities__r.size() > 0) {
                            displayWrapper.endUser = thisHeader.Direct_Customer_Eligibilities__r[0];
                            displayWrapper.endUser.ValidFromFormated__c =   displayWrapper.endUser.Valid_From__c.format();
                            displayWrapper.endUser.ValidToFormated__c =   displayWrapper.endUser.Valid_To__c.format();
                     }

             lstMainWrapper.add(displayWrapper);
              }

              //Product and End User are not Entered - #Default search
                else{
                MainWrapper displayWrapper = new MainWrapper();
                displayWrapper.priceAgreementHeader  = priceheadermap.get(thisnewDist.Price_Agreement__c);
                displayWrapper.validFromFormatted = priceheadermap.get(thisnewDist.Price_Agreement__c).Valid_From__c.format();
                displayWrapper.validToFormatted = priceheadermap.get(thisnewDist.Price_Agreement__c).Valid_To__c.format();
                displayWrapper.DistributorNumber = thisnewDist.Distributor_Number__c; 
                lstMainWrapper.add(displayWrapper); 
                 }


            }// for loop end

            if(lstMainWrapper.size() > 0) {
                    return lstMainWrapper;
            }
            else {
            return null;
            }

   }
 }
}
```

```
Lightning component(UI): Table
=============================

<table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal">
<thead>
                        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps slds-line-height_reset">

                            <th scope="col">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                   data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.priceNumberSort}">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Price_Agreement_Number}
                                        <span>
                                            <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.priceNumberSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                            size="xx-small" />
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </th>

                            <th scope="col">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                   data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.priceNameSort}">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Price_Agreement_Name}
                                        <span>
                                            <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.priceNameSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                            size="xx-small" />
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </th>

                            <th scope="col">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                   data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.priceTypeSort}">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Type}
                                        <span>
                                            <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.priceTypeSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                            size="xx-small" />
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </th>

                            <th scope="col">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                   data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.priceValidFormSort}">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Valid_From}
                                        <span>
                                            <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.priceValidFormSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                            size="xx-small" />
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </th>

                            <th scope="col">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                   data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.priceValidToSort}">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Valid_To}
                                        <span>
                                            <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.priceValidToSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                            size="xx-small" />
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </th>

                            <th scope="col">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                   data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.priceLastChangedSort}">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Last_Changed}
                                        <span>
                                            <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.priceLastChangedSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                            size="xx-small" />
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </th>

                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.PAT_Status}</div>
                            </th>

                            <!-- Product column start -->
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.productValue}">
                                <th scope="col">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                       data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.productSort}">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Product}
                                            <span>
                                                <lightning:icon
                                                                iconName="{!v.productSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                                size="xx-small" />
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>

                                <th scope="col">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                       data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.productValidFromSort}">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Valid_From}
                                            <span>
                                                <lightning:icon
                                                                iconName="{!v.productValidFromSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                                size="xx-small" />
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>

                                <th scope="col">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                       data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.productValidToSort}">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Valid_To}
                                            <span>
                                                <lightning:icon
                                                                iconName="{!v.productValidToSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                                size="xx-small" />
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>

                                <th scope="col">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                       data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.productStatusSort}">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.PAT_ProductStatus}
                                            <span>
                                                <lightning:icon
                                                                iconName="{!v.productStatusSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                                size="xx-small" />
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>

                                <th scope="col">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                       data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.productPricePerCaseSort}">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.PAT_PricePerCase}
                                            <span>
                                                <lightning:icon
                                                                iconName="{!v.productPricePerCaseSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                                size="xx-small" />
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                            </aura:if>
                <!-- Product column End -->

                <!-- End user column start-->
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.endUserValue}">
                                <th scope="col">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                       data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.endUserSort}">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.End_User_Number}
                                            <span>
                                                <lightning:icon
                                                                iconName="{!v.endUserSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                                size="xx-small" />
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                       data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.endUserValidFormSort}">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Valid_From}
                                            <span>
                                                <lightning:icon
                                                                iconName="{!v.endUserValidFormSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                                size="xx-small" />
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset"
                                       data-field="{!v.currentList}" onclick="{!c.endUserValidToSort}">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Valid_To}
                                            <span>
                                                <lightning:icon
                                                                iconName="{!v.endUserValidToSort ? 'utility:chevronup' : 'utility:chevrondown'}"
                                                                size="xx-small" />
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                            </aura:if>
            <!-- End user column end --> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.currentList}" var="record" indexVar="indx">
                            <tr class="slds-hint-parent">

                                <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Price_Agreement_Number}" scope="row">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                        <a href="" onclick="{!c.redirectToDetail}" data-selectedindex="{!record.Id}">
                                            {!record.priceAgreementHeader.Name}</a>

                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Price_Agreement_Name}" scope="row">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                       {!record.priceAgreementHeader.Price_Agr_Description__c}
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <!--If logged in user is distributor-->
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.PATWrapper.isDistributor}">
                                    <th data-label="{!$Label.c.DistributorNumber}" scope="row">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                           <!-- {!record.Distributor_Number__c}-->
                                           {!record.DistributorNumber}
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                </aura:if>
                                <!--If logged in user is End User-->
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.PATWrapper.isDistributor == false}">
                                    <th data-label="{!$Label.c.End_User_Customer_Number}" scope="row">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                           <!-- {!record.Customer_Number__c}-->
                                            {!record.CustomerNumber}
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                </aura:if>
                                <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Type}" scope="row">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                         {!record.priceAgreementHeader.Sub_Grouping__c}
                                    </div>
                                </th>

                                <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Valid_From}" scope="row">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                      <!--{!record.ValidFromFormated__c}-->
                                       {!record.validFromFormatted}
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Valid_To}" scope="row">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                       <!-- {!record.ValidToFormated__c}-->
                                        {!record.validToFormatted}

                                    </div>
                                </th>

                                <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Last_Changed}" scope="row">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                         <!-- <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!record.Price_Agreement__r.Last_Changed_Date_time__c}"  year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric" hour="2-digit"
                                            minute="2-digit" hour12="true"/>-->
                                         <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!record.priceAgreementHeader.Last_Changed_Date_time__c}"  year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric" hour="2-digit"
                                            minute="2-digit" hour12="true"/> 

                                    </div>
                                </th>

                                <th data-label="{!$Label.c.PAT_Status}" scope="row">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                         {!record.priceAgreementHeader.Price_Agreement_Status__c}
                                    </div>
                                </th>

                                <!-- For Product start-->
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.productValue}">
                                    <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Product}" scope="row">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                            {!record.product.Material_Number__c}
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Valid_From}" scope="row">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">

                                            {!record.product.ValidFromFormated__c}

                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Valid_To}" scope="row">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                                {!record.product.ValidToFormated__c}

                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th data-label="{!$Label.c.PAT_ProductStatus}" scope="row">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                            {!record.product.Product__r.Status__c}
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th data-label="{!$Label.c.PAT_PricePerCase}" scope="row">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                            <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!record.product.Price_Per_Case__c}" />
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                </aura:if>
                <!-- For Product end-->

                <!-- For End user start-->
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.endUserValue}">
                                    <th data-label="{!$Label.c.End_User_Number}" scope="row">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                            {!record.endUser.Customer_Number__c}
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Valid_From}" scope="row">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                                {!record.endUser.ValidFromFormated__c}

                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Valid_To}" scope="row">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                                {!record.endUser.ValidToFormated__c}
                                        </div>
                                    </th>
                                </aura:if>
                <!-- For End user start-->
                           </tr>
                        </aura:iteration>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

After i clicked on search (without enterinf product and end user)
[image]

Comment: Can you please attach a mock-up of the UI if you have it?

Comment: May be it sound silly. But what is a mock-up?

Comment: I have added the code for UI. which contain the table structure.

Comment: It not a stupid question. It means can you post a screenshot of the functionality of how you are building it or have envisioned it will look to users on the screen.

Comment: Got your point.

Comment: I have added the screenshot. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Since each record can have multiple child records, I would suggest going with the [`lightning:treeGrid`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid) component for showing the details. The top-level record will be of Price agreement and on expanding that you can show product details.

Something like the image below. I am suggesting this because that way it will handle all the UI for you and you can use Async loading variation of `aura:treegrid` to load child records.

You need to make 3 configurations for header and based on the Case 1/2/3, set the appropriate JSON in `data` and `columns`.

Advantages: 
      -

- You will have small components with distributed logic.
- Minimal need of wrappers and complex processing in apex.

[image: Tree Grid component]

OR:

You can use the normal table like you are using, but on the click, open a modal to show the child records.